# Python pandas: Speed up filter data with rules for each kind of data

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm comparing output of old and new system. Data as below (total set is huge):

```
transaction|item|old value|new value
00000000001|a1|12|12.1
00000000002|a1|12|12.1
00000000003|a1|12|12.4
00000000004|a1|12|12.8
00000000005|a1|12|12.9
00000000015|a2|a|ab
00000000017|a2|a|ab
00000000018|a2|a|ab
00000000019|a2|a|ab
00000000020|a3|a|ab
00000000021|a3|a|ab
00000000022|a3|a|ab
00000000023|a3|a|ab
00000000024|a3|a|ab
00000000025|a3|a|ab
00000000026|a3|a|ab
```

items are limited (20 items).

Some differences are acceptable, some are not. We need to filter out the acceptable and write additional column of why acceptable. 1 item may have several filter rules

```
EX: 00000000001|a1|12|12.1| diff smaller than 1
```

The diff above vary depend on currency of the transaction (we have a map of transaction/currency)

**My implementation:**

```
#Load the file
data=pandas.read_csv("output.diff.csv", sep=",", header = None,     names=column_names)
#get item list
items=list(data.item.unique())
#scan through each item, filter data related to item and push it to function to process each item 
for item in items:
    dataoptions[item](data[data.item == item])

dataoptions = { 'a1': process_a1,
                'a2': process_a2, 
              }
def process_a1(df):
    #merge the transaction data frame with transaction currency data frame
    df1=pandas.merge(df,tran_currency,how='left')
    df1.old=pandas.to_numeric(df1.old)
    df1.new=pandas.to_numeric(df1.new)
    df1['Diff']=df1.old -df1.new
    #filter diff
    df2=df1[((df1.Diff <=1)&(df1.Diff >=-1)&(df1.currency == ''))|((df1.Diff <=2)&(df1.Diff >=-2)&(df1.currency != ''))]
    #write to acceptable file
    df2['Rule']='tolerant 1'
    df2[column_names_rules].to_csv(acceptable_outfile + "tolerant.csv", header=False,mode='a',index=False)
    #get remain diff
    df2=df1[~((df1.Diff <=1)&(df1.Diff >=-1)&(df1.currency == ''))|((df1.Diff <=2)&(df1.Diff >=-2)&(df1.currency != ''))]
    df3=df2[column_names]

    process_a1_rule2(df3)
```

I see it still quite slow, so need your suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: What are columns of `tran_currency` dataframe? Where is column `currency` ? Is some connected `dataoptions` loop with `process_a1` ? Thank you.

Comment: tran_currency has 2 columns trấnction and currency.  Dataoptions is dic with e.g.: a1: process_a1. So it will call process_a1 when input item is a1

Comment: So need filter data by dict `Dataoptions`? Can you add it to answer with sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataoptions` is some function, faster is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply`:

```
items=list(data.item.unique())
for item in items:
    dataoptions[item](data[data.item == item])
```

is changed to:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #print (x.name)
    #print (dataoptions[x.name])
    return dataoptions[x.name](x)

df4 = df.groupby('item').apply(f)
```

---

You can change [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) - add parameter `errors='coerce'` for parsing non numeric to `NaN`:

```
df1.old=pandas.to_numeric(df1.old, errors='coerce')
df1.new=pandas.to_numeric(df1.new, errors='coerce')
```

---

Also is NOT necessary create conditions again, better is create mask and then only invert it by `~` to `df3`, for selecting by `mask` and column names use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = ((df1.Diff <=1)&(df1.Diff >=-1)&(df1.currency == ''))|
       ((df1.Diff <=2)&(df1.Diff >=-2)&(df1.currency != ''))
df2=df1[mask]

df2['Rule']='tolerant 1'
df2[column_names_rules].to_csv(acceptable_outfile + "tolerant.csv", 
                               header=False,mode='a',index=False)

df3 = df1.loc[~mask, column_names]
```

Comment: Dataoptions is dic with e.g.: a1: process_a1. So it will call process_a1 when input item is a1

Comment: Thank you, but without sample is hard verify my solution with `groupby`. So I add custom function, I think it can be helpful.

Comment: Many thanks. I applied your suggestion. So df4 is data frame return the difference remain after all filter?